# Primefaces Mobile - DataTable - select row, before event taphold occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-mobile

I have a problem in PrimeFaces Mobile with the DataTable and the event taphold.

**problem:**

- If I use the event taphold in a datatable, the event occurs, before the row can be selected.

**the desired behaviour:**

- the click or finger touch selects the row (visually through a different background color for the row too). The event taphold occurs, if I press long enough, additionally.

**first ideas, to solve the problem**

- I think, the problem is, that for row selection the .mouseup()-event is responsible and not the mousedown()-event for example. So, I have to change the event, to select the row, before the taphold-event occurs. But I don't know how.

**current source code:**

```
<p:dataTable id="music_songs" var="music" value="#{musicPlayerBean.musicSongs}" selectionMode="single" 
         selection="#{musicPlayerBean.selectedMusicSong}" rowKey="#{music.id}" style="background: white;"
         paginator="true" rows="25" tableStyleClass="ui-table-columntoggle" emptyMessage="keine Musik-Songs vorhanden">

     <p:ajax event="taphold" oncomplete="alert('Hallo');"/>

     <p:column headerText="Interpret" priority="1" sortBy="#{music.interpret}">
         <h:outputText value="#{music.interpret}"/>
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Titel" priority="1" sortBy="#{music.title}">
         <h:outputText value="#{music.title}" />
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Dauer" priority="2" sortBy="#{music.duration}">
         <h:outputText value="#{music.durationAsString}"/>
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Album" priority="2" sortBy="#{music.album}">
         <h:outputText value="#{music.album}"/>
     </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

[Examples for mobile data tables on PrimeFaces-Website](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/dataTable.xhtml)

Versions:

- JSF 2.2
- Java 1.7
- Glassfish 4
- PrimeFaces 5.2

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and add relevant info

Comment: In one of the links it is requested (required) to post version info